# Finding missing matrix values

Tags: linear-algebra

We have three matrices A; B; C that satisfy AB = C and such that

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&2&-2&*\\
2&-3&*&1\\
0&-1&2&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$B =
\begin{pmatrix}
2&3&*&4\\
-1&*&0&1\\
*&1&-2&0\\
0&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
C =
\begin{pmatrix}
*&2&5&1\\
*&1&-2&-6\\
3&1&-4&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where a  indicates a missing values. Find the missing values and show the resulting
matrices A; B; C.

After, multiplying A and B, I get the following matrix.

$$
AB =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2&-2&-2*&0\\
6&-3*&*&1\\
0&-1&-4&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Do I set AB equal to C and solve by getting it to reduced row echelon form? After that, assuming I get values for *, how do I know which * value goes to which matrix?

Comment: Label the stars $A_{1,4}$, $A_{2, 3}$, etc.  This will let you know which stars go where.

Comment: The multiplication result you have seems wrong to me.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Why do you think he think that?

Comment: I'm not sure. A matrix m x n multiplied by a matrix n x p results a matrix m x p.

Comment: Top row of $A$ times 1st column of $B$ is $(-1)(2)+(2)(-1)+(-2)(e)+(a)(0)=-4-2e$ (where I've named the *s $a,b,c,\dots$) so that, not $-2$, should be the upper left entry of $AB$. Please review how matrix multiplication works.

Comment: Do not do algebra with the * symbol, because it is not algebraic. Different instances of the symbol stand for independent numbers.

Comment: Oh I see. I just didn't add them together. Thanks for telling me to substitute * for a,b,c, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just give labels to the unspecified entries, like $a,b,c,\ldots$. And it appears that your matrix multiplication is broken. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1,2,-2,a%7D,%7B2,-3,b,1%7D,%7B0,-1,2,1%7D%7D%2a%7B%7B2,3,c,4%7D,%7B-1,d,0,1%7D,%7Be,1,-2,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,1%7D%7D-%7B%7Bx,2,5,1%7D,%7By,1,-2,-6%7D,%7B3,1,-4,0%7D%7D&dataset=) for the correct result, for instance.